# Object map not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios

I have a problem, I don't understand why i have the error "Object.map is not a function...

You can see my code here:

```
  onClick(student_id)
 {
let session_id = this.props.match.params.id
let config = {
  headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${authentication.getToken()}`
  }
}
axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sessions/${session_id}/students/${student_id}`, config)
.then(response => {
  this.props.history.push('/')
}).catch(err => console.log(err));

}

 render() {
  const students = Object.map(student => (
    <ul>
      <button onClick={this.onClick(student.id)} >Ajouter 
 {student.name} à la session</button>
    </ul>
  ));
return (
```

Can someone please guide me to solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: It's probably - most definitely - because `Object.map` is not a function. Not all objects have a `map()` method; only `Array` objects do. Definitely the `Object` prototype does not have it.

Comment: for better understanding check this once https://codeburst.io/array-vs-set-vs-map-vs-object-real-time-use-cases-in-javascript-es6-47ee3295329b

Answer (score 2):

You have assigned no value to `Object` and also you can't do this since `Object` is a reserved keyword. `Object` has no method called `map` but `Array` has.

```js
let arr = [{name: 'Name1', age: 23}, {name: 'Name2', age: 24}, {name: 'Name3', age: 21}]

let stdObj = {name: 'Name1', age: 23, student: true}

//Map an Array
arr.map(obj => console.log(obj.name));

//Map an Object
Object.keys(stdObj).map(data => console.log(stdObj[data]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only call map function on an array. Map cannot be called on objects. But however if you want to iterate over an object you can do like this, check example below

```
const obj = {'name':'somename','age':23}
Object.keys(obj).map(key => console.log(obj[key]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Object.map does not exist. What you want to do, is map over the students array (which must be present in the state/props of your component).

This can be achieved by using:

```
students.map(student => (<ul>your code here</ul>))
```